# Remove default search path when linking new dylib.

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to link new dylib to my executable, but it link it with absolute path (`/usr/local/lib/`) how can I remove this default path from the used shared libraries ?

```
otool -L ../Build/Products/Debug/myexec

../Build/Products/Debug/myexec:
/usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For macos and Mach-O binaries, `install_name_tool` command can change dynamic link libs.

- `-change old new binary` option will change one or several libs' location.
- `-rpath old new binary` will reset rpath to a new one.
- `-delete_rpath old binary` will remove the current one.
- `-add_rpath new binary` will add a new path.

However, there may be a small trouble: it seems this cmd line tool can only set the binary's rpath, not the system rpath, so that `/usr/local/lib` cannot be removed by `-delete_rpath` option.

In such case, the only option is `-change old new`.

To check rpath:

```
$ otool -l that_exec |grep -C 5 LC_RPATH
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 13152
 datasize 0
Load command 40
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path /the_binarys_rpath/here (offset 12)
```